# Access a file and extract only annotated methods thereby processing them further

Tags: java, file, methods, annotations

I have the following situation:

File1.java, File2.java .... Filen.java:
I have different java files that has say different methods method1, method2 ... methodn.
Now some of the methods within those files are annotated with annotation @annotated_method.

Now I want to create a java file which access all the files in a particular directory for File1.java, File2.java .... Filen.java and I need to profile(or do some processing) only to the methods that has been annotated with @annotated_method annotation. Profiling(or processing of that method) must be done separately for each and every annotated method.

eg.,

```
  File1.java:


    @annotated_method
    method 1{
    ...
    }

    method 2{
    ...
    }

    .
    .
    .
    @annotated_method
    method 13{
    ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    method n
    {
    ...
    }




    File2.java:


    @annotated_method
    method x1{
    ...
    }

    method x2{
    ...
    }

    .
    .
    .
    @annotated_method
    method x13{
    ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @annotated_method
    method xn
    {
    ...
    }
```

As given above I need to profile(or process) only the methods 1,13,x1,x13,xn.

It will be great if I get to know how to get the annotated part of a code to be processed further according to various requirements.

I have gone through the usage of getAnnotations(); isAnnotationpresent();

Comment: create an Arraylist<Method> and put in every Method where getAnnotations() contains your annotation. Then process the List

Comment: Then i guess you might load in the file, copy annotated method-blocks into a new file (search for your annotation, then just copy everything from annotation until closing bracket of method) and process the resulting file.

Comment: @kleopi how should I copy only the annotated method-blocks into a new file by searching for annotation. Also I need to save the method name and filename as a log. Can you please code it roughly, so that I can get a clear picture on it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @kleopi actually I need to find the running time of each method that is annotated with '@annotated_method' annotation and store them as a log.

Comment: If the running times are short (like  few seconds), just write a program which executes every annotated method once and count the time

Comment: Updated my answer, thiscode might help you. All you need now is the Class object. Im sure you can somehow parse it from a .class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class TimeMeasurer {
    public static void gettimes(Class c) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        List<Method> methods=Arrays.asList(c.getMethods());
        for(Method m:methods)
        {
            List<Annotation> ans= Arrays.asList(m.getAnnotations());
            List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Annotation a:ans)
            {
                classes.add(a.getClass());
            }
            //if(classes.contains(Deprecated.class))

            {
                if (m.getParameterCount()!=0)
                {
                    System.err.println("The method "+m.getName()+" could not be executed as it has parameters. Use a method with example values instead!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Executing Method: "+m.getName());
                    long stamp = System.nanoTime();
                    Object result=m.invoke(c);
                    long timeconsumed=System.nanoTime()-stamp;
                    System.out.println("Result of Method: "+result);

                    System.out.println("Time needed: "+timeconsumed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        gettimes(EndloseFormel.class);
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Executing Method: testmethode
Result of Method: 123
Time needed: 5748
```

Comment: can you please help me on how to invoke non-static methods as m.invoke(c) only invokes static method else it throws exception!

Comment: If I remember it right you can add an Object as parameter which is then assigned to execute the method

Comment: I don't get that can you please elaborate it?

Comment: method.invoke(instance, myArgument); where instance is the Object which should execute that method

Comment: Consider I have two classes ExampleNothing.class, ExampleNothing1.class. They have two methods each non-static method1 ,static method2 in ExampleNothing.class and non-static method method3, static method4 in ExampleNothing1.class. Now I need to invoke all methods method1, method2, method3, method4 one after another like how you have mentioned in your code. How do I do it? Here the class names are passed as connand line arguments.

Comment: Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();
This gives you an instance of the class.

Comment: consider another example with Test.java which has two methods display , displaynow like this: public void display() {System.out.println("I'm non-static method");} public void displaynow() { System.out.println("I'm non-static method as well"); } You can see this has no parameters, Now when I do m.invoke(c); java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at Profiler.Calculatefactors(Profiler.java:61). Where m is display() in first iteration and displaynow() in second iteration, value of c is Test.class.

Comment: if I perform Object obj = Class.forName(c.getName()).getConstructor().newInstance(); 
                  m.invoke(obj);                                                            with no parameters I get the following exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Test.<init>()
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
 at Profiler.Calculatefactors(Profiler.java:60)
 at Profiler.profile(Profiler.java:34)
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: Add a generic constructor